# QWebSocketServer - not releasing memory

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, websocket

First, I ran valgrind on my secure websocket server application and found an issue (in Qt Memcheck I had to check *"External Errors"* to see it) - some bytes are *definitely lost* - pointing to my `main` just where my `QCoreApplication::exec()` call is. In the stack trace, after the call, there are just some Qt libraries, starting with `libQt5Core` and ending with `libQt5WebSockets`. The number of lost bytes increases with the number of connections made. I double-checked that I delete all `QWebSocket` instances returned by `QWebSocketServer::nextPendingConnection()`. I do also delete the `QWebSocketServer` instance. Interesting thing is, that valgrind does not report any error when running *sslechoserver* demo nor when running my server in unsecure mode (no SSL). I don't know if this is an actual issue.

Secondly, **more importantly**, I am observing that **consumed memory keeps increasing with every new connection** (even though the old connections are closed and their `QWebSocket` instances are deleted, actually most of the time there is 0 or 1 active connection) **in both my application and the *sslechoserver* demo**. I used *systemmonitor* on Ubuntu and *Windows Task Manager* on Windows for the observation. The reported memory usage are dozens of megabytes after tens of thousands connections were made, while at the beginning of the application's lifecycle it was ~1.5 MB.

I tested it with Qt 5.5.1 and 5.6.0 (GCC on Ubuntu, MSVC on Windows).

Am I getting something wrong? Is there a bug in Qt's websockets? Is the *sslechoserver* demo incorrect?

---

**UPDATE:** I did also try *echoserver* demo (without SSL) and the consumed memory keeps increasing there too.

---

**UPDATE 2:** We concluded there must be a bug in Qt. The bug report is here:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53503

Comment: Is there any update on this issue; Is this still happening? Btw, I was also interested to know, how many simultaneous connections, a Qt Web/TCP server can handle. Is it scalable upto million?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: I had a doubt that the underlying `QTcpSocket` had to be managed by the user. However, it seems to be not true as of Qt 5+. Please refer: [Is the QTcpSocket (or QSslSocket) which underlies a QWebSocket -- destroyed by itself when a socket error happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58870100/is-the-qtcpsocket-or-qsslsocket-which-underlies-a-qwebsocket-destroyed-by-i/58870755#58870755).
The incorrect part of the answer is striked-through below.

---

When we upgrade a `QTcpSocket` to a `QWebSocket` using `QWebSocketServer::handleConnection()` method, both the sockets remain active on different memory addresses!

In other words, the `QWebSocket` acts as a wrapper and all the socket communication happens via the underlying `QTcpSocket`. **So for every 1 Web socket we manage, there is 1 more hidden TCP socket.**

<strike>Both the sockets should be handled using `deleteLater()` mechanism when they are meant to be destroyed.

This scenario is true at least for the TCP to Web upgradation.</strike>